# Geofencing products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, geolocation, woocommerce, geocoding

I am developing a small, local delivery website using Wordpress and Woocommerce. I am trying to implement a conditional field or part of code that geofences (may not be the correct term) products to their postcodes. For example people who type in a particular postcode radius are only able to view a selection of products available in their area. It seems I'm looking for a type of SauceyApp.com or Just-Eat.co.uk type search feature. I'm assuming this requires the use of some form of Google Maps plugin. I have been searching for weeks and can't even get insight on where to begin. I was wondering if anyone knew how I can go about this or even a vague idea on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps has a [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) where you can put in a location and radius and get an autocomplete for searching local places and lists of places to map by category. To get a users location you could use the [Geolocation Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) which is supported by most browsers (IE 9+) or a geolocation service. All that's required is an [Api key from google](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862), location, and radius. They you can send in options to filter the data. Information on these parameters is [listed here in googles docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests).

An example query would look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&types=food&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

There are several open source wrappers around this api to give you something to start with:

[python-google-places](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places)

[google-places-api-java](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java)

[Ruby wrapper for Google Places](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places)